# FirebaseUI Auth - Facebook Login error : Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to integrate FirebaseUI Auth library. Google sign-in and Email sign-in are working fine but I have a problem setting up Facebook Login.
This is my code:

```
user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                   startMainActivity();
                   finish();
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
```

When I click the facebook button all the login process goes well (in my facebook profile I see the app in my apps list) but firebase doesn't create the user and I'm stuck on the login page.
In Android Monitor I have the following lines (the app doesn't crash):

```
E/CredentialSignInHandler: Unexpected exception when signing in with credential
                           com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook ]
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblv.zzce(Unknown Source)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd.zzcf(Unknown Source)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbly$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

The error that Firebase shows up is only "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook" without any code or error message... I don't know what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem. Because I have done everything suggested here but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 20):

I have the same problem, the facebook auth on firebase was enabled but pointing to another application id that is different with one I am working on.

So need to make sure the application id from "firebase console/ authentication/ sign in method/ facebook" is the same with application id on your facebook console.

I took me several hours to figure out, hope it useful.

Answer (score 18):

Go to [Facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com) and select your app from the dropdown menu. Then go to **Settings -> Advanced** and find **Is App Secret embedded in the client?** select **No** from the toggle button and done. Refer this image link if you face any difficulty finding the option. [Facebook Login error : Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Dbk.png)

Comment: My consoles does not have this setting  Is App Secret embedded in the client?

Comment: Amit you are my savior! I spent hours trying to figure out this! I could give you a thousand arrow-ups if could! haha

Comment: @RajuyourPepe You first have to enable the "
Native or desktop app?" toggle to see the option

Comment: Update 2021: Settings > Advanced > Native or desktop app? Select Yes from the toggle button and Is App Secret embedded in the client? will appears

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and resolved it after re-checking the App Secret on the top right of the screen at Facebook developers page. Make sure the App Secret in Firebase Authentication(Facebook Provider) is the same as the app secret in Facebook developers page.

[App secret on Facebook developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0lwS.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

make sure this is correct with facebook dev page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the both: App secret and App ID from the Facebook developers page and Firebase Authentication (Facebook Provider), because Firebase by default has his own ids

Answer (score 1):

This issue started appearing after I changed the `google-services.json` in my app.
I changed this so it points to new Firebase environment. This new environment also uses a new Facebook app registration.

I checked all settings for my new environment:

- Facebook `App ID` in Firebase
- Facebook `App secret` in Firebase
- Android `Key Hashes` in Facebook

Everything was correctly configured, but the I still got the error.

After a long search I realized that the new build did not fully clean my `Flutter` solution. So the new build still used they old cached `google-services.json`.

After a `flutter clean` and `flutter build` it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure it out for hours. It is most likely a wrong App-ID within your firebase auth configuration (facebook). In my case, I had entered the bundle name of my app instead of the App-ID of facebook. Hope it helps.

[app configuration within firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CujxS.png)

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverFlow, Can You please be more precise and add more details?

Comment: To properly use facebook login, you need to complete several steps which are described pretty well here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-develop-a-great-facebook-login-flow-with-firebase-and-ionic-656a295c4fe9. In my answer I referred to step "Setup Facebook sign-in on Firebase" where you have to enter the App-ID on the firebase console. Be sure to use the correct Facebook App-ID there

Answer (score 0):

For me, resetting the App Secret did the trick.
Go to `Settings --> Basic` and then click `'Reset'` beside your `'App Secret'`

Comment: I don't see this option

Comment: @AlonShlider You have to be admin to see this option in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the switch toggled saying "Yes" to "Is this a native or desktop app". I then re-entered the app secret in Firebase and made sure to add the OAuth Redirect URI to the Facebook app.