# Facebook Login Error Using Firebase on Android : Unsuccessful debug_token response

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have enabled Facebook as one of the providers in firebase console and have double checked that the Facebook app_id, app secret match in both firebase and facebook. Also, firebase Oauth redirect URI is the only valid oauth redirect URI present in my facebook app settings.

On running the Facebook login flow, I verified several times that the login flow is successful and I am properly getting an Oauth token from facebook. However, it is the `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` code whose `Task<AuthResult>` object fails with the following exception

```
10-28 18:01:02.471 3883-3883/com.my.android.app D/ray232: signInWithCredential:failure
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:{&quot;error&quot; ]
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdlj.zzak(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdkl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdlu.zzal(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdlw.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdll.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

This is the code snippet throwing the exception :

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(launchActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("ray232", "signInWithCredential:success");
                launchActivity.onLoginRequired(false);
            } else {
                Log.d("ray232", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(launchActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                launchActivity.onLoginRequired(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

There is an identical question on SO for this issue [Unsuccessful debug token response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357232/firebaseui-auth-facebook-login-error-unsuccessful-debug-token-response-from), but I have tried everything suggested in the answers but to no avail.

I am using the following versions:

```
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this??

Comment: @AlleyOOP No buddy. I just removed facebook auth for the time being. Are you getting this as well ?

Comment: I posted my particular solution here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371020/using-accesstoken-to-retrieve-firebase-user-causing-firebase-error-with-facebook

Answer (score -3):

On the first parameter of `addOnCompleteListener`, try using `launchActivity.this`

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: How does this make sense?