# Using AccessToken to retrieve Firebase user causing Firebase error with Facebook auth: "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook" Code 190

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, token

Setting up Facebook Authentication with Firebase on Android and getting the following  pesky error:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"BLR\/UAx2fzn"}} ]
```

My goal is not to get rid of this error, it's to be able to get information about the user from Firebase. At the moment, even though I seem to able to get an not-null, un-expired token, there's no entry for a Facebook user in my Firebase Console. IOW, how can I get this line to not fail?

--> `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)`

To reproduce, I start the app from scratch (logged out) and proceed to my LoginActivity. I select the **Continue with Facebook** `LoginButton` and select **Continue**. I currently have my app's logic so upon success of the callback, it stays in the LoginActivity and I get the error featured above.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.***.datingapp.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.***.datingapp.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Login";

    private EditText loginEmailEditText;
    private EditText loginPasswordEditText;
    private TextView loginStatusTextView;
    private TextView loginDetailTextView;
    private Button loginEmailButton;
    private Button loginRegisterButton;
    private LoginButton loginFacebookButton;
    private Button loginFacebookLogoutButton;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginEmailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_login_email);
        loginPasswordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_login_password);
        loginStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_login_status);
        loginDetailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_login_details);
        loginEmailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login_email);
        loginRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login_email_register);
        loginFacebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebookLogin);
        loginFacebookLogoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebookSignout);

        loginEmailButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        loginRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        loginFacebookLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        loginFacebookButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult + " - " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                updateUI(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                updateUI(null);
            }
        };
        loginFacebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.

        AccessToken fbAccessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (fbAccessToken != null && fbAccessToken.isExpired())
            handleFacebookAccessToken(fbAccessToken);
        else {
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(currentUser);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_login_email:
                if (loginEmailButton.getText().toString().equals(getText(R.string.login_activity_sign_in)))
                    signIn(loginEmailEditText.getText().toString(), loginPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
                else
                    signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.button_login_email_register:
                createAccount(loginEmailEditText.getText().toString(), loginPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
                break;
            case R.id.buttonFacebookSignout:
                signOut();
        }
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = loginEmailEditText.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            loginEmailEditText.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            loginEmailEditText.setError(null);
        }

        String password = loginPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            loginPasswordEditText.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            loginPasswordEditText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        if (!validateForm())
            return;
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            loginStatusTextView.setText(R.string.login_activity_status_auth_failed);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
        if (!validateForm())
            return;
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            signOut();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Resuming.",
//                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        updateUI(null);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {
            loginStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.emailpassword_status_format,
                    user.getEmail(), user.isEmailVerified()));
            loginDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_format, user.getUid()));
            loginEmailButton.setText(getText(R.string.login_activity_sign_out));
            loginFacebookButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            loginFacebookLogoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            loginStatusTextView.setText(R.string.login_activity_status_signed_out);
            loginDetailTextView.setText(null);
            loginEmailButton.setText(getText(R.string.login_activity_sign_in));
            loginFacebookButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loginFacebookLogoutButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

I've noticed that when I include the line `handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());` in the callback, I get the error, but I otherwise don't. But excluding the line doesn't seem like a permanent solution, because how can I retrieve user information then?

- I have set up everything concerned with the App ID and App Secret.
- I have configured my Facebook app's settings as precisely as I can gather.
- I have included the required meta tag in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my this issue by:

(drum roll please)

Deleting my Facebook Application through the Facebook Developer's Console and *creating a new, identical application*. I then copied the app id and secret to Firebase Console auth for Facebook signin, updated my manifest, and voila, it worked.

I'm not marking this solution as the "right" answer because it didn't "fix the problem." I was just going off the intuition that this was a FirebaseException (an internal error) after I had already double-triple-quadruple checked all of my Facebook app's configuration settings and code.

Comment: There is just something really wrong with Firebase integration with Facebook Auth. It randomly stops working, leaving you in the lurch.